# SWIG json object parse into Client Side json

Tags: json, angularjs, swig-template

I am using Angularjs, but i guess it can be simple JavaScript.

What I have done:

```
console.log(JSON.parse({{{JSON.stringify(items)}}}));
```

`items` has the JSON object. I am getting the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o`.

I am not sure if it's the correct way to do this. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out:

```
{{{items|raw|json_encode}}}
```